# How would you markup an event with multiple showtimes?

Tags: schema.org

The only info I found on this was a question asked on Moz and the response was to create multiple events. That feels very counter intuitive. If the venue, performer, performance, and price are all the same, should each showtime really get it's own individual event?

[Google has a section for marking up event listings](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings), but it doesn't explain how that's supposed to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) makes clear that the event has to happen "at a certain time", and it recommends:

> Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.

If you would use a single `Event` item for multiple events, it wouldn’t be possible to use many of the properties, or it wouldn’t be clear what they mean:

- [`attendee`](http://schema.org/attendee): which of the multiple events did the person attend?
- [`eventStatus`](http://schema.org/eventStatus): what if one showtime was cancelled?
- [`isAccessibleForFree`](http://schema.org/isAccessibleForFree): what if one of the multiple events is free?
- [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers): for which showtime is this offer?
- [`recordedIn`](http://schema.org/recordedIn): from which showtime is this recording?
- etc.

**tl;dr**: You have to provide multiple `Event` items.

Comment: That still feels very counter intuitive. Movie theaters, for example, have multiple showtimes that don't need any of the other information to change. It seems like it would make way more sense to have a property for a list of showtimes that could override the default settings. The way that it's currently set up seems to create a lot of room for error. I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just saying it seems strange.

Comment: @JohnRPerry: Yes, I think such a property would make sense. Maye I’ll find some time to later to check if something like this was proposed for Schema.org. -- Perhaps the definitions for the [`superEvent`](http://schema.org/superEvent)/[`subEvent`](http://schema.org/subEvent) properties could be adjusted so that it’s also possible to use them in situations like this.